# List files in pairs using Bash

Tags: bash, loops, scripting

I have a collection of files in a directory. They are left and right audio tracks for each filename. I want them to be listed by bash as **filename_l filename_r** so I can use sox to merge each one together. But I am not having any luck with a bash loop.

I need the files listed in the loop as 1-2 3-4 5-6 7-8 9-10 11-12 et cetera. But I am not sure how to go about this.

```html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  653K Oct 25 14:24 05_wasteland2_str_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  648K Oct 25 14:24 05_wasteland2_str_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.5M Oct 25 14:24 amb0010_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.5M Oct 25 14:24 amb0010_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.4M Oct 25 14:24 amb0016_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.4M Oct 25 14:24 amb0016_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.9M Oct 25 14:24 amb0017_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.9M Oct 25 14:24 amb0017_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.6M Oct 25 14:24 amb0019_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.6M Oct 25 14:24 amb0019_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.8M Oct 25 14:24 amb001_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.8M Oct 25 14:24 amb001_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.0M Oct 25 14:24 amb006_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.0M Oct 25 14:24 amb006_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.9M Oct 25 14:24 amb007_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  1.9M Oct 25 14:24 amb007_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  4.5M Oct 25 14:24 amb01_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  4.5M Oct 25 14:24 amb01_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  3.0M Oct 25 14:24 amb02_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  3.0M Oct 25 14:24 amb02_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.5M Oct 25 14:24 amb03_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.5M Oct 25 14:24 amb03_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.2M Oct 25 14:24 amb04_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.2M Oct 25 14:24 amb04_r.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.3M Oct 25 14:24 amb05_l.ogg
-rwxrwxrwx  1 jason jason  2.3M Oct 25 14:24 amb05_r.ogg
```

I tried this bash loop, but it does not do what I need, but there must be something small I am missing.

```html
declare -a files=(*.ogg)
for (( i = 0; i < ${#files[*]}; ++ i ))
do
  echo ${files[$i]} ${files[$i+1]}

done
```

There are 486 files in total, and doing this by hand will take too logn and be prone to mistakes. Every loop I have tried has gone 1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5 et cetera, I need this do work differently, so each file is listed with it`s partner. The existing loop I have gives this output.

```html
05_wasteland2_str_l.ogg 05_wasteland2_str_r.ogg
05_wasteland2_str_r.ogg amb0010_l.ogg
amb0010_l.ogg amb0010_r.ogg
amb0010_r.ogg amb0016_l.ogg
amb0016_l.ogg amb0016_r.ogg
amb0016_r.ogg amb0017_l.ogg
amb0017_l.ogg amb0017_r.ogg
amb0017_r.ogg amb0019_l.ogg
amb0019_l.ogg amb0019_r.ogg
amb0019_r.ogg amb001_l.ogg
amb001_l.ogg amb001_r.ogg
amb001_r.ogg amb006_l.ogg
amb006_l.ogg amb006_r.ogg
amb006_r.ogg amb007_l.ogg
amb007_l.ogg amb007_r.ogg
amb007_r.ogg amb01_l.ogg
amb01_l.ogg amb01_r.ogg
amb01_r.ogg amb02_l.ogg
amb02_l.ogg amb02_r.ogg
```

This is not what I am after. But I hope there is a simple solution to this problem.

I want to be able to output this.

05_wasteland2_str_l.ogg 05_wasteland2_str_r.ogg

For each of the files, _l and _r. I want to be able to use sox to merge each pair of files.

That way I can use this to merge the files.

sox -M 05_wasteland2_str_l.ogg 05_wasteland2_str_r.ogg 05_wasteland2_merged.ogg

But listing the files in pairs is what I am finding very difficult. This could end up being quite challenging.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show  your required output from your sample input. (We only need 4-6 lines of sample input, unless there are special cases). Good luck.

Comment: These code blocks are not runnable in the browser, so they should not be fancy “code snippets”. Please just use basic code blocks – use ``` above and below each block or indent each block by at least four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that there are pairs of otherwise identically named files with `_l` and `_r`:

```sh
for f in *_l.ogg; do
    echo "$f" "${f/%_l.ogg/_r.ogg}"
done
```

This loops over all files ending in `_l.ogg`, and then prints pairs of these files together with the file where `_l.ogg` (anchored at the end of the string) is replaced by `_r.ogg`.

Comment: I used this script to merge all files using your answer.

for f in *_l.ogg; do
    sox -M "$f" "${f/_l/_r}" ../musicfiles\/$f.ogg
done

This merged all files and this worked just fine. A couple of files had _r and _l in their filenames and they were skipped, but this is something I can fix manually. Thank you.

Comment: Using `"${f/%_l.ogg/_r.ogg}"` instead of "${f/_l/_r}" would work on files that had other occurrences of "_l" in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently iterating over files, but you want to iterate over *pairs* of files. There are half as many pairs of files as there are files (`${#files[*]}/2`).

The indexes need to become `$i*2` and `$i*2+1`.

Complete code, with these changes included:

```
declare -a files=(*.ogg)
for (( i = 0; i < ${#files[*]}/2; ++ i ))
do
  echo ${files[$i*2]} ${files[$i*2+1]}

done
```

This answer requires minimal changes to your existing code. However, it assumes that the `files` array is sorted and consists entirely of pairs of files in the expected format. Benjamin W.’s answer does not make these assumptions.